# will carry flag be set after CMP?

Tags: unsigned, msp430, cmp, carryflag

(MSP430 16 bit)

```
CLR[.W]   R14 
CMP[.W]   #0x0200, R14 
JC        #1234
```

How can I know if Carry flag will be set?

Can `CMP[.W]   #0x0200, R14` make Carry flag be set?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_CPU : JC = Jump if (carry/)higher or same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to take a look at the documentation.
Section 3.4.6.14 of the [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau144) says:

> **Syntax**
> `CMP src,dst` or `CMP.W src,dst`
>
> **Description**
> The source operand is subtracted from the destination operand. […]
> The two operands are not affected and the result is not stored; only the status bits are affected.
>
> **Status Bits**
> […]
> C: Set if there is a carry from the MSB of the result, reset otherwise

So the carry flag will be set if subtracting 0x200 from zero needs a carry.

This meaning of the carry flag is made clearer in the documentation of JC/JHS in section 3.4.6.24:

> **Description**
> […] JC (jump if carry/higher or same) is used for the comparison of unsigned numbers (0 to 65536).
>
> **Example**
> R5 is compared to 15. If the content is higher or the same, branch to LABEL.
>
> ```
> CMP #15,R5
> JHS LABEL    ; Jump is taken if R5 >= 15
> ......       ; Continue here if R5 < 15
> ```